cloud storage signedUrl public url client email error
I am working in nodejs to upload files(audio/video) and I want to be able to viewed the uploaded file from internet which I have set appropriate permission in the GCP Cloud Storage Bucket. I installed @google-cloud/storage package and upload file, the file i uploaded got uploaded successfully. I actually wanted to get the signedUrl of the uploaded file because I want to keep signedUrl(the public url) so that user can view the file from anywhere some other time.
*******WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
I actually wanted to get the signedUrl of the uploaded file after uploading it because I want to keep signedUrl(the public url) so that user can view the file from anywhere some other time.
*******THE ERROR I GOT

Error: Cannot sign data without client_email.
at GoogleAuth.sign (C:\Users\Documents\sample\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:788:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async sign (C:\Users\Documents\sample\node_modules@google-cloud\storage\build\cjs\src\signer.js:219:35) {
name: 'SigningError'
}

********WHAT I HAVE TRIED
I have set my command line google application credentials using the following command but no success:
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='test-project-sa.json'

Below are the code I have tried
npm install @google-cloud/storage

const uploadFile = async (fileToUpload, fileOutputName) =>{

      const projectId = process.env.GCS_PROJECT_ID;
      const keyFileName = process.env.GCS_KEYFILENAME;

       const storage = new Storage({projectId, keyFileName});

      let finalOutputFileName = fileOutputName + Date.now();

      let publicUrl = null;

  try{
      const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GCS_BUCKET_NAME);

      bucket.acl.default.add({
        entity: "allUsers",
        role: storage.acl.READER_ROLE
      }, function (err) {})

      const storagepath = `UserAvatars/${finalOutputFileName}`;

      const fileUploadResult = await bucket.upload(fileToUpload, {
      destination: storagepath, 
      predefinedAcl: 'publicRead', // Set the file to be publicly readable
            /* metadata: {
                contentType: "application/plain", // Adjust the content type as needed
            } */
  })

   const fileRef = await storage.bucket(process.env.GCS_BUCKET_NAME).file(`UserAvatars/${finalOutputFileName}`);

//This line shows that the file was successfully updated, it logged to console  
fileRef.exists().then(function (data) {
    console.log("File in database exists ");
});
 

const response = await fileRef.getSignedUrl({
  version: "v4",
  action: "write",
  expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  //contentType: filetype,
  extensionHeaders: {
      'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'
  }
});
 
    publicUrl = response[0];


      console.log(fileUploadResult[0].metadata.mediaLink + "\n \n");

      console.log(`The public url for this file is \n \n ${publicUrl} \n \n`);
    
  
  return publicUrl;
 
 }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
 }
}


The file successfully got uploaded to the google cloud bucket but the SignedUrl cannot be generated. I have googled how to solve the client_email ut i couldn't get a comprehensive help.
Please how do i go about this?
Thank you in advance

Does your Service Account JSON key include a client_email field?

Making the object (file) to be publicly readable is inconsistent with using a signed URL. Signed URLs are intended to provide access to the bearer of the URL assuming that the bearer otherwise has no access to the file i.e. it generally wouldn't be publicly readable. If it were, there's no need for the signed URL

Thank you @DazWilkin, yes my Service Account JSON key has client_email in it but what I don't understand is that the client_email is different from the gmail account id i am using for my gcp account. I moved away from the Uniform Bucket Storage to Fine Grained Bucket so that I can grant permission to file individually. I have spent over 24hrs on this. Is there a way I can view the bucket files from web or mobile app without generating signedUrl  public url? I just want to publicly have access to the files in the bucket. I can upload successfully

I have granted all required permissions and roles to the service account and even  resorted to creating Application Default Credential json file so that I can impersonate my Service Account and that is not working too. All these methods I have tried is just to ** simply be able to view my files in Google Cloud Storage Bucket from web apps and mobile app ** and I have already made the bucket publicly accessible. My development environment is NodeJS and I can upload the files successfully but need to view it.

Okay, you've many questions and this isn't a good forum. I encourage you to read Google's documents as they are comprehensive. Answering some of your questions: Service Account's have their own email address: {account}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com; if you're a Project|Bucket viewer (e.g. using your Gmail account), you can browse Buckets using Google's storage browser (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project={project}; for public files (!) you can use URLs of the format: https://storage.cloud.google.com/{bucket}/{object}

Thank you so much @DazWilkin, the https://storage.cloud.google.com/{bucket}/{object} allows me to view the image when i inserted the url in html code. I appreciate your contribution and time over this. The point remains that I have granted all required roles and permissions to the Service Account principal(client_email generated by GCP Cloud storage for my Service Account json key file, the client_email generated is different from my gmail account used to setup GCP) but I still get "Permission Denied - Forbidden" error if I tried to use the signedUrl() method in my code. I thank you sir

I'm unable to repro your issue. I can only recommend that you look at Google's example (this works for me). And/or pare back your example to the basic code and then enhance it to discover the error. One curiosity to me is that you're using action: "write" even though you reference only reading. Good luck!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
